# Best way to synchronize playback over 3g networks

Tags: java, android, mobile, time

I am trying to figure out a way to synchronize rhythm playback on 2+ mobile android devices.

Achieving good precision on WiFi / LAN is simple (Very low latency) but I need a good solution for 3G networks with variable high latency..

One idea I came up with is sending and timing messages and using average time-spans to compensate latency but this idea seems absurd and I'm kinda sure there are better other ways to solve this..

care to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first of all try to create a as close as possible synchronized clock across all devices that you can use as a reference.

When devices communicate they always include their local synchronized time with the message, this way you can always figure out the difference between when you received the message and when it was transmitted, and also always know that the time the message states you should play a beat is the same across all devices.

The real difficulty here being synchronizing the watches.. I would start by reading this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

There is a JAVA based NTP client here:
http://commons.apache.org/net/examples/ntp/NTPClient.java

If you get that to work, there are a number of NTP servers across the world.
http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html

Answer (score 0):

I have actually recently tried to solve the very same question myself. The best solution I have found was the NTP (Network Time Protocol).

The main drawback is that it can take long time to synchronise over a high latency network. So you need to have an app that is running quite a while before you need to have the devices synchronized.

The application I´m working on is not yet tested with perfect timings so I can´t promise that this is a viable solution. But one worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

If your devices are close enough together, you could see whether you are able to use Bluetooth to speed up peer-to-peer synchronisation, while using NTP to get the global time -- probably by adding Bluetooth-linked phones as extra remotes in your NTP config.  This would entail pairing end-user devices, which may be an issue for you.